# shapesharer and verdant force

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a [Shapesharer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140200) copy an opponents [Verdant Force](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=verdant%20force). The Verdant Force puts a 1/1 green Saproling creature token onto the battlefield at the beginning of each upkeep. The Shapesharer becomes a copy of target creature until your next turn.

So if I copy my opponents Verdant Force on my turn I'm going to assume that I only get one saproling token and not two? ie. I'd get one for his upkeep but not for mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest chance you would have to activate [Shapesharer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shapesharer)'s ability is in the Upkeep step<sup>[1]</sup>. Since the beginning of your upkeep step has already gone by, the ability gained from [Verdant Force](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Verdant%20Force) will never get a chance to trigger on your turn<sup>[2]</sup>.

---

1. The Untap step comes first, but you do not gain priority during the Uptap step, so you do not get to activate abilities in the Untap step.
2. If you have more than one Upkeep steps for some reason (e.g. [Paradox Haze](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Paradox%20Haze)), and if you activated Shapesharer's ability in the first Upkeep step, the ability it gained from Verdant Force would trigger in the second and subsequent Upkeep steps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. Upkeep is the first phase of a turn, so when your turn next comes around, the only upkeep that would have occured is your opponents (assuming 1v1)

Comment: Upkeep is not a phase, and it's not the first step

Comment: I had always assumed that untapping was part of the upkeep

Comment: Nope; untap, upkeep and draw are three distinct steps during your beginning phase. If your upkeep involves tapping stuff, you can't then untap it, so the distinction is pretty important!

Comment: Another notable distinction: you can't put anything on the stack in the untap step. Essentially, nothing (except untapping) actually happens until upkeep. (See for example the new [Inspired mechanic](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/bornofthegodsmechanics#anchor1) in Born of the Gods.)